# Why are Apache Projects sensitive to Java Versions?

Tags: java

Why is it that I can't keep the latest version of Java, that I have to downgrade to Java 8 for almost all Apache Projects?
Is Java not backward compatible?
A program compiled to ByteCode on a older JDK should be run perfectly well on the JVM of a newer JDK.
Why is it that I have to go through the pains of building from source?
I thought this was one of the things that Java was supposed to overcome!

Comment: Java 9 introduced modules. Java 11 rewrote Java to use modules extensively. That is the main reason. And, in Java 11, the entire methodology of recommended packaging changed (there is no longer an official JRE).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch But still, a bytecode of Java8 should run on Java11 tho right? This just makes me understand that older JVM can't understand newer code.

Comment: And it does. Java 8 class files work in Java 11. What are you asking? How are you going to run that bytecode? There is no longer an official JRE.

Comment: I'm not following :|

Comment: *Why is it that I have to go through the pains of building from source?* You don't. Why do you think you do? Building from source isn't going to make a project compatible with Java 11 if the compiled code doesn't work in Java 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is not exclusive to Apache projects. With the newer Java Versions it's not so much about 'understanding the older code' but more about 'am I allowed to use these features the old way' (modularization).

In some cases the older code also uses features that are just not part of the latest JDK any more (e.g. removal of JEE Modules). I'd recommend to read [Oracles Migation Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/migrate/index.html) for more on this topic.

For (bigger) projects the Migration to >Java8 is something that needs to be planned and organized and takes a lot of time.

Comment: Thank you for the simple enough explanation. So let me get this straight. Modules were removed after Java 8, and hence older programs any programs using modularisation could not run on the newer JVMs.